# (IOS)How to start a operation without adding it to NSOperationQueue?

Tags: nsoperationqueue

I want to subclass a NSOperation and use the *start* method to start it asynchronously. According to my understanding, I should override the method of *main, start, asynchronous,executing,finished* method.And Then start it use the start method, then it will spawn a new thread itself and execute itself on that thread. But as my test, it does not spawn a new thread, instead it execute on the main thread.It makes me confused, which place I am wrong, can someone tell me,how to start a operation without adding it to NSOperationQueue please?

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by reading the apple doc, I should spawn a thread myself.